# Simplify this query, I'm sure there is a better way (Select from multiple UNION ALL)

Tags: sql, performance, union

This is my current query, which works, but it does not seem very elegant. 
Unfortunately the tables have not been normalised and I need to get a sum from 4 separate number fields, by four different code fields. 
The code fields hold someone's name and the same name may or may not appear in each of the four code fields. 
So, I want to sum for all occurrences of a name whether in CODE 2, 3, 4, 5 by totalling the respective Numb 2, 3, 4, 5 fields.

```
Select Organisation, code, sum(numb)as mynumb
from
(
(Select organisation, code2 as code, numb2 as numb 
    from dbo.continfo ci 
    join dbo.conthist ch on ci.pvkey = ch.pvkey
    where Not code2 is Null)
UNION ALL
(Select organisation, code3 as code, numb3 as numb 
    from dbo.continfo ci 
    join dbo.conthist ch on ci.pvkey = ch.pvkey
    where Not code3 is Null)
UNION ALL
(Select organisation, code4 as code, numb4 as numb 
    from dbo.continfo ci 
    join dbo.conthist ch on ci.pvkey = ch.pvkey
    where Not code4 is Null)
UNION ALL
(Select organisation, CODE5 as code, NUMB5 as numb 
    from dbo.continfo ci 
    join dbo.conthist ch on ci.pvkey = ch.pvkey
    where Not CODE5 is Null)
) as f
GROUP BY Organisation, code
ORDER BY mynumb desc
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Does each row contains only the same value for code2..code5 fields or null, or a row can contain different values for the code2..code5 fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it more efficient, by unpivoting the data.  I prefer to do the unpivot explicitly by using a `cross join` and `case` statement in the `select` clause:

```
select organization, code, sum(numb)
from (Select organisation,
             (case when n.n = 1 then code1
                   when n.n = 2 then code2
                   when n.n = 3 then code3
                   when n.n = 4 then code4
                   when n.n = 5 then code5
              end) as code, 
             (case when n.n = 1 then numb1
                   when n.n = 2 then numb2
                   when n.n = 3 then numb3
                   when n.n = 4 then numb4
                   when n.n = 5 then numb5
              end) as numb
      from dbo.continfo ci join
           dbo.conthist ch
           on ci.pvkey = ch.pvkey cross join
           (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5
           ) n
     ) t
where code is not null;
```

This should generate the data from the join once and create five rows for each one in the result set, one for each code.

The difficulty of doing this suggests why you really want to have another association/junction table.  This would have one row per `pvkey` and `code`.  If you had such a table, this query would be a simple join and aggregation.

Comment: Hi Thanks, I knew there was an elegant solution... ps. I also wish they had a normalised structure, as it would be just a simple join.

Answer (score -1):

Most RDBMs have commands to show you the result of optimizing the query. Check what that tells you, and decide if it is worth your while to bum it by hand.